# Oracle & sqlplus connection

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to make a SQLplus connection to a remote Oracle DB following [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client) and it's failing at this step `sqlplus username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID` with the error:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

I'm using the following syntax:

```
sqlplus username/password@//x.x.x.x:1521/SID
```

I know the DB is reachable and my passwords are correct (verified with Oracle SQL dev). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"invalid username/password"* -- this error almost always means exactly what it says.  It indicates that the incorrect username and password combination was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's probably because your password contains special characters and you will need to escape them with back-slash or just use quotes around

```
sqlplus 'username/password@//x.x.x.x:1521/SID'
```

please also note that, AFAIK, if your password was contains one or both of `/` or `@` characters, you will still need to use back-slash escape only for them and back-slash itself `\` too.